# How to update a bulk selection of fields using field calculator in QGIS 2.8.1

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have an attribute table showing vegetation communities.  The table has three columns ("ID", "Veg Comm" and "Area_ha".  Instead of having to copy and paste text after each polygon created into each field (i.e. coastal wattle scrub), is there a way to highlight a selection and mass copy?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the recent versions of QGIS, if you have a selection the 'Only update x selected features' checkbox is enabled as default. Any expression written will be updates to the chosen column of the selected rows. Below picture is from QGIS 2.8.1.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not a direct answer to your question as you are looking for a post-processing step, but as you say that you will do this step "after each polygon created into each field" you may be interested in the setting `Setting` > `Options` > `Digitizing` > `Reuse laste entered attribute values`. This will set the previously used attribute values as default while digitizing and may therefore remove the need for a post-processing step at all.